# How to check if the exact words contained in an array are present in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

Hi I would like to know how to check if the exact words contained in an array in Javascript are present in a string, like this

```
let filter = ["action", "romance"];
let genres = "action sci-fi romance horror";
```

this should be true

Comment: You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). But first you should read the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: You could use regex here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @jabaa, you can use `every` and `includes`:

```js
const matches = filter.every((word) => genres.includes(word));
```

Comment: The OP was asking for exact _words_ so I'm assuming a substring match won't suffice since this will incorrectly match `comedy` to `tragicomedy` for example.

Comment: @CherryDT The question is _"how to check if the exact words contained in an array in Javascript are present in a string"_. It doesn't say that it has to be an exact word in the string. The array `['comedy']` and the string `'tragicomedy'` should return true.

Comment: Yes, and I would thereby say that the _exact word_ `abc` isn't present in the string `abcdef`, the _character sequence_ is. It would be in `abc def`, just like you won't consider the _number_ `42` to be present in the array `[193854, 1125016, 9912]` even though the byte `2A` (42) exists as part of `98 2A 11 00` (1125016) in memory, while it is in `[12, 42, 33]`...

Comment: @CherryDT Looks like the question is unclear and should be closed until this is clarified.

Comment: You are right, I can see now how one could also understand it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

First, split the string into words by [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) at a [word boundary](https://javascript.info/regexp-boundary):

```js
const splitGenres = genres.split(/\b/)
```

This will also put things *between* words like punctuation and spaces into elements, but you probably don't need to care about them because you are searching for specific known values.

If you need to normalize case and always match to lower-case values, you can also convert the results to lower-case by appending `.map(word => word.toLowerCase())` to the line above ([mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element to its [lower case representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)). If your filter may also not be normalized yet, you can do the same to the filter array as well.

This whole method is under the assumption that the input string can have any format like a regular sentence. If this isn't the case and instead it's always a list separated by a single space, then you can also use `.split(' ')` instead.

Then, check whether [all of the words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in your filter array are also [contained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the list of words which we have now extracted:

```js
const allMatching = words.every(word => splitGenres.includes(word))
```

You then have a boolean in `allMatching` telling you whether your filter matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let filter1 = ["action", "romance"];
let filter2 = ["action", "romance", "not_present"];
let genres = "action sci-fi romance horror";

function isAllWordPresent(str, arr) {
  let count = 0;

  const result = arr.map((s) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${s}\\b`);
    const result = regex.test(str);
    if (result) count++;
    return result;
  });
  return result.length === count;
}

console.log(isAllWordPresent(genres, filter1));
console.log(isAllWordPresent(genres, filter2));
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Just because it's possible?

Comment: Since this is a filter I suppose it may have user input as its source. I would therefore suggest [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1871033) `s` before embedding it into a regular expression.

Comment: I just come up with this alternate solution so I thought it should be worth sharing...